# How can I extract days in each month in this case, using PHP

Tags: php, date, extract, days

I have 2 dates:

$d1= 28/11/14

$d2= 13/01/15

So I need to print each month with the days, like this:

November = 2 days

December = 31 days

January = 13 days

any idea how can I do this? I also need to print the month and these dates have only the number of the month, so I need to convert this too. Also including the leap years. I'm using PHP.

Comment: What you're asking for isn't clear. What do you want to do?

Comment: http://php.net/datetime. load the first date, start incrementing months until you reach the last date, calculate the days-in-month for each of those intervals.

Answer (score 0):

PHP date http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
So it would be

```
date('t', strtotime($englishDate));
```